# Find the business day number in a pay period given a date, using MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am wanting to aggregate data using a derived value that I am struggling to calculate: "business day number in the pay period". I have provided a further description below:

In any given month, there are two pay periods. The first period commences on the first business day of the month, and concludes at COB on the last business day leading up to and including the 15th (eg: it may conclude on 14th because 15th is a Saturday). The second period commences on the following business day after the previous period has concluded, and ends at COB on the last business day of the month. How can I transform a datetime column into an integer representing which day of the pay period a tuple belongs to, that way data can be aggregated based on "business day number in a pay period".

If possible, I would prefer not to require intermediate tables or user-defined functions to do this; preferably using arithmetic only. Essentially a query like:

```
SELECT (<arithmetic on datetime col here>) as businessDayNumber, count(someCol)
FROM someTbl
GROUP BY businessDayNumber;
```

Here is sample data which provides the outcome that I desire:

```
CREATE TABLE sampleData (
    dataId INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    dataDt DATE NOT NULL,
    someValue INT NOT NULL
);


INSERT INTO sampleData (dataDt, someValue) VALUES ('2020-01-01', 51),
 ('2020-01-01', 62),
 ('2020-01-01', 23),
 ('2020-01-01', 54),
 ('2020-01-02', 61),
 ('2020-01-02', 35),
 ('2020-01-02', 47),
 ('2020-01-02', 69),
 ('2020-01-02', 32),
 ('2020-01-02', 83),
 ('2020-01-02', 13),
 ('2020-01-03', 51),
 ('2020-01-03', 62),
 ('2020-01-03', 23),
 ('2020-01-03', 54),
 ('2020-01-03', 61),
 ('2020-01-03', 35),
 ('2020-01-06', 54),
 ('2020-01-06', 61),
 ('2020-01-06', 35),
 ('2020-01-06', 47),
 ('2020-01-06', 69),
 ('2020-01-06', 32),
 ('2020-01-06', 83),
 ('2020-01-06', 13),
 ('2020-01-07', 51),
 ('2020-01-07', 62),
 ('2020-01-07', 23),
 ('2020-01-07', 54),
 ('2020-01-07', 61),
 ('2020-01-07', 35),
 ('2020-01-07', 47),
 ('2020-01-07', 69),
 ('2020-01-07', 32),
 ('2020-01-08', 51),
 ('2020-01-08', 62),
 ('2020-01-08', 23),
 ('2020-01-08', 54),
 ('2020-01-08', 61),
 ('2020-01-08', 35),
 ('2020-01-08', 47),
 ('2020-01-08', 69),
 ('2020-01-08', 32),
 ('2020-01-08', 83),
 ('2020-01-08', 13),
 ('2020-01-09', 35),
 ('2020-01-09', 47),
 ('2020-01-09', 69),
 ('2020-01-09', 32),
 ('2020-01-09', 83),
 ('2020-01-09', 13),
 ('2020-01-09', 54),
 ('2020-01-09', 61),
 ('2020-01-09', 35),
 ('2020-01-09', 47),
 ('2020-01-10', 69),
 ('2020-01-10', 32),
 ('2020-01-10', 83),
 ('2020-01-10', 13),
 ('2020-01-10', 51),
 ('2020-01-10', 62),
 ('2020-01-13', 83),
 ('2020-01-13', 13),
 ('2020-01-13', 54),
 ('2020-01-13', 61),
 ('2020-01-13', 35),
 ('2020-01-13', 47),
 ('2020-01-14', 69),
 ('2020-01-14', 32),
 ('2020-01-14', 83),
 ('2020-01-14', 13),
 ('2020-01-14', 51),
 ('2020-01-14', 62),
 ('2020-01-14', 23),
 ('2020-01-14', 54),
 ('2020-01-15', 61),
 ('2020-01-15', 35),
 ('2020-01-15', 47),
 ('2020-01-15', 69),
 ('2020-01-15', 32),
 ('2020-01-16', 51),
 ('2020-01-16', 62),
 ('2020-01-16', 23),
 ('2020-01-16', 54),
 ('2020-01-16', 61),
 ('2020-01-16', 35),
 ('2020-01-16', 47),
 ('2020-01-16', 69),
 ('2020-01-16', 32),
 ('2020-01-16', 83),
 ('2020-01-16', 13),
 ('2020-01-16', 51),
 ('2020-01-16', 62),
 ('2020-01-17', 23),
 ('2020-01-17', 54),
 ('2020-01-17', 61),
 ('2020-01-17', 35),
 ('2020-01-17', 47),
 ('2020-01-17', 69),
 ('2020-01-17', 32),
 ('2020-01-17', 83),
 ('2020-01-17', 13),
 ('2020-01-17', 54),
 ('2020-01-20', 47),
 ('2020-01-20', 69),
 ('2020-01-20', 32),
 ('2020-01-20', 83),
 ('2020-01-20', 13),
 ('2020-01-20', 51),
 ('2020-01-20', 62),
 ('2020-01-20', 23),
 ('2020-01-20', 54),
 ('2020-01-20', 61),
 ('2020-01-20', 35),
 ('2020-01-20', 47),
 ('2020-01-20', 69),
 ('2020-01-20', 32),
 ('2020-01-21', 83),
 ('2020-01-21', 13),
 ('2020-01-21', 54),
 ('2020-01-21', 61),
 ('2020-01-21', 35),
 ('2020-01-21', 47),
 ('2020-01-21', 69),
 ('2020-01-21', 32),
 ('2020-01-21', 83),
 ('2020-01-21', 13),
 ('2020-01-21', 51),
 ('2020-01-21', 62),
 ('2020-01-21', 23),
 ('2020-01-21', 54),
 ('2020-01-21', 61),
 ('2020-01-21', 35),
 ('2020-01-21', 47),
 ('2020-01-21', 69),
 ('2020-01-21', 32),
 ('2020-01-21', 83),
 ('2020-01-21', 13),
 ('2020-01-22', 54),
 ('2020-01-22', 61),
 ('2020-01-22', 35),
 ('2020-01-22', 47),
 ('2020-01-22', 69),
 ('2020-01-22', 32),
 ('2020-01-22', 83),
 ('2020-01-23', 13),
 ('2020-01-23', 51),
 ('2020-01-23', 62),
 ('2020-01-23', 23),
 ('2020-01-23', 54),
 ('2020-01-23', 61),
 ('2020-01-24', 35),
 ('2020-01-24', 47),
 ('2020-01-24', 69),
 ('2020-01-24', 32),
 ('2020-01-25', 35),
 ('2020-01-25', 47),
 ('2020-01-25', 69),
 ('2020-01-27', 35),
 ('2020-01-27', 47),
 ('2020-01-27', 69),
 ('2020-01-27', 32),
 ('2020-01-27', 83),
 ('2020-01-27', 13),
 ('2020-01-27', 51),
 ('2020-01-27', 62),
 ('2020-01-28', 23),
 ('2020-01-28', 54),
 ('2020-01-28', 61),
 ('2020-01-28', 35),
 ('2020-01-28', 47),
 ('2020-01-28', 69),
 ('2020-01-28', 32),
 ('2020-01-29', 69),
 ('2020-01-29', 32),
 ('2020-01-29', 83),
 ('2020-01-29', 13),
 ('2020-01-29', 51),
 ('2020-01-29', 62),
 ('2020-01-29', 23),
 ('2020-01-30', 54),
 ('2020-01-30', 61),
 ('2020-01-30', 35),
 ('2020-01-30', 47),
 ('2020-01-30', 69),
 ('2020-01-30', 32),
 ('2020-01-31', 35),
 ('2020-01-31', 47),
 ('2020-01-31', 69),
 ('2020-01-31', 32),
 ('2020-01-31', 83),
 ('2020-01-31', 13),
 ('2020-01-31', 54),
 ('2020-01-31', 61),
 ('2020-02-02', 47),
 ('2020-02-03', 54),
 ('2020-02-03', 61),
 ('2020-02-04', 35),
 ('2020-02-04', 51),
 ('2020-02-04', 62),
 ('2020-02-04', 23),
 ('2020-02-04', 54),
 ('2020-02-06', 61),
 ('2020-02-06', 35),
 ('2020-02-06', 47),
 ('2020-02-06', 69),
 ('2020-02-07', 23),
 ('2020-02-07', 54),
 ('2020-02-07', 61),
 ('2020-02-07', 35),
 ('2020-02-07', 47),
 ('2020-02-08', 23),
 ('2020-02-08', 54),
 ('2020-02-08', 61),
 ('2020-02-08', 35),
 ('2020-02-08', 47),
 ('2020-02-08', 69),
 ('2020-02-08', 35),
 ('2020-02-08', 47),
 ('2020-02-08', 69),
 ('2020-02-08', 32),
 ('2020-02-09', 83),
 ('2020-02-09', 13),
 ('2020-02-09', 54),
 ('2020-02-09', 61),
 ('2020-02-09', 35),
 ('2020-02-09', 47),
 ('2020-02-09', 69),
 ('2020-02-09', 32),
 ('2020-02-09', 83),
 ('2020-02-09', 13),
 ('2020-02-09', 51),
 ('2020-02-09', 62),
 ('2020-02-09', 23),
 ('2020-02-09', 54),
 ('2020-02-10', 61),
 ('2020-02-10', 35),
 ('2020-02-10', 47),
 ('2020-02-10', 69),
 ('2020-02-10', 32),
 ('2020-02-10', 51),
 ('2020-02-11', 62),
 ('2020-02-11', 23),
 ('2020-02-11', 54),
 ('2020-02-11', 32),
 ('2020-02-11', 83),
 ('2020-02-12', 13),
 ('2020-02-12', 51),
 ('2020-02-13', 62),
 ('2020-02-13', 23),
 ('2020-02-13', 54),
 ('2020-02-13', 61),
 ('2020-02-13', 35),
 ('2020-02-13', 47),
 ('2020-02-14', 69),
 ('2020-02-14', 32),
 ('2020-02-14', 83),
 ('2020-02-14', 13),
 ('2020-02-14', 54),
 ('2020-02-14', 61),
 ('2020-02-14', 35),
 ('2020-02-14', 47),
 ('2020-02-15', 69),
 ('2020-02-15', 32),
 ('2020-02-15', 83),
 ('2020-02-15', 13),
 ('2020-02-15', 51),
 ('2020-02-16', 62),
 ('2020-02-16', 23),
 ('2020-02-16', 54),
 ('2020-02-16', 61),
 ('2020-02-16', 61),
 ('2020-02-16', 35),
 ('2020-02-16', 47),
 ('2020-02-16', 69),
 ('2020-02-16', 32),
 ('2020-02-16', 83),
 ('2020-02-16', 13),
 ('2020-02-16', 51),
 ('2020-02-16', 62),
 ('2020-02-17', 23),
 ('2020-02-18', 35),
 ('2020-02-18', 47),
 ('2020-02-18', 69),
 ('2020-02-18', 32),
 ('2020-02-18', 83),
 ('2020-02-18', 13),
 ('2020-02-18', 51),
 ('2020-02-18', 62),
 ('2020-02-18', 23),
 ('2020-02-18', 54),
 ('2020-02-18', 61),
 ('2020-02-18', 35),
 ('2020-02-18', 47),
 ('2020-02-18', 69),
 ('2020-02-18', 32),
 ('2020-02-19', 51),
 ('2020-02-19', 62),
 ('2020-02-19', 23),
 ('2020-02-19', 54),
 ('2020-02-19', 61),
 ('2020-02-19', 35),
 ('2020-02-20', 47),
 ('2020-02-20', 69),
 ('2020-02-20', 32),
 ('2020-02-20', 83),
 ('2020-02-20', 13),
 ('2020-02-20', 51),
 ('2020-02-20', 62),
 ('2020-02-20', 23),
 ('2020-02-20', 54),
 ('2020-02-20', 61),
 ('2020-02-20', 35),
 ('2020-02-20', 47),
 ('2020-02-20', 69),
 ('2020-02-20', 32),
 ('2020-02-21', 83),
 ('2020-02-21', 13),
 ('2020-02-21', 54),
 ('2020-02-21', 61),
 ('2020-02-21', 35),
 ('2020-02-21', 47),
 ('2020-02-21', 69),
 ('2020-02-21', 32),
 ('2020-02-21', 83),
 ('2020-02-21', 13),
 ('2020-02-21', 51),
 ('2020-02-21', 62),
 ('2020-02-21', 23),
 ('2020-02-21', 54),
 ('2020-02-21', 61),
 ('2020-02-21', 35),
 ('2020-02-21', 47),
 ('2020-02-21', 69),
 ('2020-02-21', 32),
 ('2020-02-21', 83),
 ('2020-02-21', 13),
 ('2020-02-22', 54),
 ('2020-02-22', 61),
 ('2020-02-22', 35),
 ('2020-02-22', 47),
 ('2020-02-22', 69),
 ('2020-02-22', 32),
 ('2020-02-22', 83),
 ('2020-02-23', 13),
 ('2020-02-23', 51),
 ('2020-02-23', 62),
 ('2020-02-23', 23),
 ('2020-02-23', 54),
 ('2020-02-23', 61),
 ('2020-02-24', 35),
 ('2020-02-24', 47),
 ('2020-02-24', 69),
 ('2020-02-24', 32),
 ('2020-02-25', 35),
 ('2020-02-25', 47),
 ('2020-02-25', 69),
 ('2020-02-25', 32),
 ('2020-02-25', 83),
 ('2020-02-25', 13),
 ('2020-02-25', 51),
 ('2020-02-25', 62),
 ('2020-02-25', 23),
 ('2020-02-25', 54),
 ('2020-02-25', 61),
 ('2020-02-26', 35),
 ('2020-02-26', 47),
 ('2020-02-26', 69),
 ('2020-02-26', 32),
 ('2020-02-26', 83),
 ('2020-02-26', 13),
 ('2020-02-26', 54),
 ('2020-02-26', 61),
 ('2020-02-27', 35),
 ('2020-02-27', 47),
 ('2020-02-27', 69),
 ('2020-02-27', 32),
 ('2020-02-27', 83),
 ('2020-02-27', 13),
 ('2020-02-27', 51),
 ('2020-02-27', 62),
 ('2020-02-28', 69),
 ('2020-02-28', 32),
 ('2020-02-29', 69),
 ('2020-02-29', 32),
 ('2020-02-29', 83);
```

[and in a SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f0717d).

Comment: Now if you put that all into an SQL Fiddle it would be great

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I didn't think of that, done!

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH cte AS ( SELECT someValue, 
                     DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY DATE_FORMAT(dataDt, '%Y%m'), 
                                                     DAY(dataDT) <= 15
                                        ORDER BY dataDT) businessDayNumber
              FROM sampleData 
              WHERE DAYOFWEEK(dataDT) BETWEEN 2 AND 6 )
SELECT businessDayNumber, COUNT(someValue)
FROM cte
GROUP BY businessDayNumber;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7d703a918bcb6f33037c3037713545f5)